# How is $-\sum b_{i}w_{i} + \sum b_{i}w_{i}\frac{p(w)}{p(w) + \eta_{i}}$ equal to $-\sum b_{i}w_{i}\frac{\eta_{i}}{p(w) + \eta_{i}}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm new to these types of equations and my professor told me to study a paper for my research proposal, I stumbled upon this equation and I can't wrap my head around it. How are these 2 equations equal?

$$-\sum b_{i}w_{i} + \sum b_{i}w_{i}\frac{p(w)}{p(w) + \eta_{i}} = -\sum b_{i}w_{i}\frac{\eta_{i}}{p(w) + \eta_{i}} < 0  $$

Comment: What's $1 - \frac{a}{a+b}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{p(w)}{p(w)+\eta_{i}}+\frac{\eta_{i}}{p(w)+\eta_{i}}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

The method that I found thanks to @ConMan is this,
$$-\sum b_{i}w_{i} + \sum b_{i}w_{i}\frac{p(w)}{p(w) + \eta_{i}}$$

Taking $\sum b_{i}w_{i}$ as common,

$$-\sum b_{i}w_{i}(1-\frac{p(w)}{p(w) + \eta_{i}})$$

Simplifying $1-\frac{p(w)}{p(w) + \eta_{i}}$ we get,

$$-\sum b_{i}w_{i}\frac{\eta_{i}}{p(w) + \eta_{i}}$$